# Error while importing the file

Tags: r

I am importing my file and getting the following error.
Can anyone help me

```
bcg_8_rtgs_in2 <- read.table("C:/Users/Goel Kartik/Desktop/SBI/Analytics leads/Data from SBI/New folder/bcg_8_rtgs_in.txt", sep="|", header=TRUE, row.name=1)
```

Error is

```
Error in read.table("C:/Users/Goel Kartik/Desktop/SBI/Analytics leads/Data from SBI/New folder/bcg_8_rtgs_in.txt",  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bcg_8_rtgs_in2 <- read.table("C:/Users/Goel Kartik/Desktop/SBI/Analytics leads/Data from SBI/New folder/bcg_8_rtgs_in.txt", sep="|", header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you have two rows with same name. To start, try changing the repeated row names.